# Two series questions

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to correct an old quiz.  I want to see if I have sufficiently corrected the second problem.  The first I am still a bit unsure what to do.

(1)  Show that the following series is divergent if $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|\alpha|<1$.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+\alpha^k}$$

The above I wasn't sure what to do so I left it blank.

(2)  Use the root test to decide whether or not the following series converges:
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{3^6}+...$$

First note: $a_n =\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2^n} \text{ if n is odd}\\ \frac{1}{3^n} \text{ if n is even } \end{cases}$.

So $\liminf a_n = \sqrt[2n]{\frac{1}{3^n}}=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\limsup a_n = \sqrt[2n-1]{\frac{1}{2^n}}=1$  So the sequence diverges.  I just want to make sure I got the values correct on this one.

Comment: In the second problem, the numbers are going down very fast, of course we have convergence. The calculations of the limits second line from the end are not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $\alpha \in (-1,1)$, then $1 + \alpha^k \leq 2$ so that

$$
\frac{1}{1 + \alpha^k} \geq \frac{1}{2}.
$$

For the second one, since $\frac{1}{3} \leq \frac{1}{2}$, then:

$$
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \dots \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{2^k} = 1
$$

If you want to use the root test: Note that

\begin{align}
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2^n}} = \frac{1}{2} < 1
\end{align}
so the series converges absolutely.

Comment: Note that question (2) asks for the root test to be used.  I agree that it is simpler not to use the root test, as you have done.  Further, what you've done shows the OP has made a mistake.  But part of the answer should be identifying and correcting that mistake.

Comment: For 1, is it because the sequence is unbounded and hence the series does not converge?

Comment: @Pete: Thank you for the comment.  I will amend my post.

Comment: @jdla: Another reason for 1) is that the terms do not have limit $0$.